# ExecuteStoreQuery not working with DateTime setter

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-4.0, objectcontext, executestorequery

I'm having trouble getting `ExecuteStoreQuery` to work correctly with my custom class which has a `DateTime` member. It gets the default `DateTime` value (1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM) instead of what is in the database.

```
List<MyInfo> results = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<MyInfo>(SELECT [StartTime] FROM [dbo].[Records] WHERE [Type] = 1).ToList();
```

MyInfo class definition:

```
public class MyInfo
{
    private DateTime startTime;
    public DateTime StartTime
    {
        get { return startTime; }
        set { startTime = value; }
    }
}
```

However if I query using `DateTime` instead of MyInfo, the correct date is returned.

```
List<DateTime> results = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<DateTime>(SELECT [StartTime] FROM [dbo].[Records] WHERE [Type] = 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Although i am confused with your question, but instead of confusion i am trying to help based on best of my understanding. ;-)

Quick and easy way:

1. If you have trouble returning date time only, then you can use

   ```
   var ls = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<MyInfo>("Select StartTime from YourTable");

   List<DateTime> dt= new List<DateTime>();
   foreach(MyInfo i in ls)
   {
     dt.Add(ls.StartTime);
   }
   ```
2. If you want to return list of your custom class then, it will be simply

   ```
   var list = Context.ExecuteStoreQuery<MyInfo>(Your_Sql_Query_Here).ToList();
   ```
3. If only one class is required, I hope SIngleOrDefault() will work.

   ```
   var cls = Context.ExecuteStoreQuery<MyInfo>Your_Sql_Query_Here).SingleOrDefault();
   ```
4. If you need only single value then

   ```
   var scalar = Context.ExecuteStoreQuery<Object>(Your_Sql_Query_Here).FirstOrDefault();
   ```